# Custom headers possible with URLRequest/URLStream using method GET?

Tags: actionscript-3, http-headers

Quite simple really:

```
var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest();
req.url="http://somesite.com";
var header:URLRequestHeader=new URLRequestHeader("my-bespoke-header","1");
req.requestHeaders.push(header);
req.method=URLRequestMethod.GET;
stream.load(req);
```

Yet, if I inspect the traffic with WireShark, the `my-bespoke-header` is not being sent. If I change to `URLRequestMethod.POST` and append some data to `req.data`, then the header is sent, but the receiving application requires a GET not a POST.

The documentation mentions a blacklist of headers that will not get sent. `my-bespoke-header` is not one of these. It's possibly worth mentioning that the originating request is from a different port on the same domain. Nothing is reported in the policyfile log, so it seems unlikely, but is this something that can be remedied by force loading a crossdomain.xml with a `allow-http-request-headers-from` despite the fact that this is not a crossdomain issue? Or is it simply an undocumented feature of the Flash Player that it can only send custom headers with a POST request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can gather, it seems like your assumption about the lack of custom headers support for HTTP GET is indeed an undocumented feature (or a bug?) in the standard libraries.

In any case, you might want to see if [as3httpclient](http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclient/) would fit your purposes and let you work around this issue. Here's a relevant snippet from a [post](http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/flash_and_actionscript/http_authentica.php) in the blog of the developer of this library:

> *"I was not able to set the header of a
>   HTTP/GET request. Macromedia Flash
>   Player allows you set the header only
>   for POST requests. I discussed this
>   issues with Ted Patrick and he told me
>   how I can us Socket to achieve the
>   desired and he was very kind to give a
>   me code-snippet, which got me
>   started."*

Comment: That's more-or-less what we are doing at the moment (rolling our own http), but the reliance on a socket connection means that the connection is not proxy aware unlike URLRequest/URLStream, and fails behind many corporate firewalls.

Comment: Worse than that, using raw sockets then opens up the whole cross-domain security can of worms, with the need to have a policy file served on port 843. Which is blocked by many firewalls...

Answer (score 6):

If this limitation was undocumented at one time, that's no longer the case.  See:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLRequest.html#requestHeaders

"[...] **Due to browser limitations, custom HTTP request headers are only supported for POST requests, not for GET requests.** [...]"