# AS3 - Adding a post to Blogger blog from Flash

Tags: json, actionscript-3, oauth-2.0

I would like to add a post to a Blogger blog from Flash.
The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost) says that you can add a post for a blog by sending a POST request to the post collection URI with a post JSON body.

Blogger example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8070105920543249955/posts/
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "8070105920543249955"
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}
```

How can that be done with AS3?

Comment: You want to use a URLLoader and the JSON library to do this. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486852/how-to-post-json-data-using-actionscript-3-0), the unaccepted answer at the bottom shows one way to do it.

Comment: I'm getting a "stream error". Is this how the URL should look like? `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1234/posts?access_token=[token]` My complete AS3 code: http://pastebin.com/qtY2jWnU

Comment: That seems OK, except you need to put in the appropriate ID for your blog (not 1234) and also pass a valid OAuth token (for authentication). I've never used the blogger API so I can't really suggest where to get those other than by reading the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `URLLoader` class alongside with `JSON.encode()` method do something like this:

```
var data:Object = {};
data.kind = "blogger#post";
data.title = title;
data.content = content;
data.blog = {};
data.blog.id = id;

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.domain.com");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = JSON.encode(data);

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
loader.load(request);
```

Comment: I'm still getting a "stream error". How can the **authorization**  be added the to the URL? From the example: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8070105920543249955/posts/
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */ https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost
Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Take a look at this link: http://blogs.adobe.com/charles/2012/05/oauth-2-0-library-for-actionscript.html