# Action script 3 /Json Vend api

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have undertaken a project to create a mobile application using flash professional 6.

I am creating the app for a friend of mine who has just opened a store and has signed up to using the vend P.O.S system.

He wants the app to be able to get and post data from the vend system via the api.

The API vend give is a RESTful api that returns responses as json.

My question is how would i go about starting this in flash professional 6?

i am using flash professional as i am used to it and, i know since flash player 11, comes with a json encoder/decoder. However i am not sure whether this would actually help me in achieving what i need.

Would it be for instance better to have flash communicate with a php file that in turn posts and gets from the api ,or just have it communicate with the api itself?

Would i instead of using json to post data be better off having the app post using rest?

what is the authentication process in flash to access the server to use the api?
 I have read up on urlrequest and urloaders in actionscript3, but i am still confused as how to implement this to get the desired out come.

if any one could point me in the right direction of post some sample script that could show a draft that i need that would be perfect.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Vend API but you can do JSON with the AS3 API from the client (unless the terms and conditions of the service mandate conditions on any API keys, for example).

On first glance, the code snippets from [How to post JSON data using Actionscript 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486852/how-to-post-json-data-using-actionscript-3-0) should still work. The update I notice there is that you can use the new JSON class directly instead of the `com.adobe.serialization.json` namespace.

Comment: hi thanks for your response.i checked that post before and its definitely booked marked ,but what i really need  is an example where  flash uses a working authentication method to access a restful api .

Comment: You're right, you mentioned "authentication", sorry I missed that. Is it basic authentication?

Comment: yeah i believe so, simple http authentication

Answer (score 0):

**this is the answer to my question. its simple but it does what i need.**

var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.yourdomian.com");

var myLoader = new URLLoader();

myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onload);

myLoader.load(myRequest);

function onload(evt:Event):void
{

```
var myOutput:Object = JSON.parse(myLoader.data);


trace(myOutput);
```

}